# segmentation fault weird

Tags: linux, ubuntu, client, segmentation-fault

Problem: When i tried to compile my file and run, it has segmentation problem. When I passed the file to my friend (he is using the same version of ubuntu), the server will be able to run. I am wondering why?

Below will be my code for the whole page.
Personally I feel that there is no problem with it but I will just paste it for reference in case anyone asks for it.

```
void readNStoreData ()
{
char words[MAX];
char *wholeLine;
char* delimiter = ",";
int cflag = 0;
int x, count = 0;
char input;

FILE *countryFile;
countryFile = fopen("Countries.txt","r");

if (!countryFile) {
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while (fgets (words, MAX - 1, countryFile) != NULL)
{
    //atof to convert string to double
    //split a single line into individual tokens indicating , as the delimeter
    //afterwards store them into array
    wholeLine = strtok (words, delimiter);
    strcpy (records [count].TDL, wholeLine);
    wholeLine = strtok (NULL, ",");
    strcpy (records [count].cName, wholeLine);
    wholeLine = strtok (NULL, delimiter);
    strcpy (records [count].FIPS104, wholeLine);
    wholeLine = strtok (NULL, delimiter);
    strcpy (records [count].ISO2, wholeLine);
    wholeLine = strtok (NULL, delimiter);
    strcpy (records [count].ISO3, wholeLine);
    wholeLine = strtok (NULL, delimiter);
    records [count].ISO = atof(wholeLine);
    wholeLine = strtok (NULL, delimiter);
    strcpy (records [count].cCapital, wholeLine);
    wholeLine = strtok (NULL, delimiter);
    strcpy (records [count].cRegion, wholeLine);
    wholeLine = strtok (NULL, delimiter);
    strcpy (records [count].cCurrencyName, wholeLine);
    wholeLine = strtok (NULL, delimiter);
    strcpy (records [count].cCurrencyCode, wholeLine);
    wholeLine = strtok (NULL, delimiter);
    records [count].cPopulation = atof(wholeLine);
count++;
}
fclose(countryFile); //close file
}
```

I hope someone will be able to spot the mistake somewhere.
Thanks to advance to those who helped!

run the gdb and the error is actually this line.
it is situated in this function.

```
    l(gdb) frame 1
    l#1  0x08048936 in readNStoreData () at testserver.c:61
    61                      strcpy (records [count].cName, wholeLine);
```

Comment: Did you try to debug with `valgrind`, `gdb`, perhaps `strace`? Do you know on what line the error occurs? I'm not going to debug this for you, this is horrible code, why did you use `strcat` like that if you know about `sprintf`?

Comment: @cha0site i have debugged and here is the error.

Answer (score 2):

I **strongly suggest** you to learn to use a [debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger), such as [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). You can install it on ubuntu by `sudo apt-get install gdb`

Here is a short [tutorial](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html).

[Google finds](http://www.google.fi/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=gdb%20tutorial%20segmentation%20fault) many more [examples](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~srhuang/teaching/cmsc212/gdb-tutorial-handout.pdf)

**EDIT**:

Since you now have GDB running, try setting a [breakpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint) before `run`:

`(gdb) br testserver.c:61`

and after you do `run` you should be able to `print` the various variables and see which one is illegal.

Comment: (gdb) frame 1
#1  0x08048936 in readNStoreData () at testserver.c:61
61                      strcpy (records [count].cName, wholeLine);

Comment: @Andres: what are you posting it for? It is _your_ answer :) That is a buffer overrun or corrupted src/dest pointers.

Comment: @sehe, to be frank i dont really know what can i do with it. and what i should do to make it right. any comments?

Comment: @Andres: the call to strcpy fails. Simply check all arguments to strcpy. Here is the man page: http://www.opengroup.org/sud/sud1/xsh/strcpy.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `strcpy` fails. You pass bad parameters into it (see http://www.opengroup.org/sud/sud1/xsh/strcpy.htm for documentation).

If you want *us* to analyze this, you  need to show us

- how `records` is defined,
- what the element struct type is defined like,
- how you initialize the `records` array, to how many elements,
- how you limit `count` to not go beyond the capacity of the `records` array
- how you make sure that `records[count].cName` (presumably either `char*` or `char[]`) is large enough to contain the token parsed by `strtok`

> ***Note*** The largest possible token is `MAX` characters, since it could be the MAX linelength returned by `fgets` + 1 trailing NUL character iff there isn't a single `delimiter` character in the input.
>   
>   This should get you underway.

I have a sneaking suspicion that you may have forgotten to initialize the receiving array (`records`) alltogether, but again, we can't know unless you show more code.